# Using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging can you filter for a single EventID?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I'd like to produce a log file that contains only log output from a particular EventId (or EventIds).  Is such functionality supported?

Answer (score 2):

If you plug in Serilog as the provider, you can continue logging through *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging* but apply Serilog's filtering to limit what is sent to the log file.

To do that you'd use the following Serilog configuration:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly("EventId.Id = 9")
    .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs/log-{Date}.txt")
    .CreateLogger();
```

(Where `9` is whatever event id you want to include.)

You can plug in Serilog with https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore, and to compile this example you'll also need to install the *Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile* and *Serilog.Filters.Expressions* packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to config Serilog using the appsettings file you can use something like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Settings.Configuration", "Serilog.Expressions"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
    },
    "WriteTo": [{
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "log.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": "120",
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Filter": [{
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
                "expression": "EventId.Id = 101"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the using field you have to put all Serilog package that you are importing, then config a sink for writing the logs and finally define a filter.

I almost spent a whole morning trying to achive that so I hope it helps you